# how to quit script prematurely on purpose on appveyor

Tags: travis-ci, appveyor

In a `.travis.yml` file I can add a line `- exit` and it will [stop the script](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/11147357234d0166c9ec96c4d9e328464b884da3/.travis.yml#L378) and not continue with the other statements.

Is there a way to do the same for the `build_script:` part of an `appveyor.yml` file?

I tried using [`- exit /B 0`](https://github.com/onqtam/tests/blob/eba4012dca6cff15fc39cc82f7a6f6817bc77b15/appveyor.yml#L64) but still the other statements after it are executed.

Comment: Not understanding where the batch-file comes into play with your question.  I don't see any batch-file code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not implemented yet, please watch [this](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1373) GitHub issue.

Comment: I'd like for a simple way (like using exit) in addition to an API way, thanks.

Comment: with current design exit will either fail the build or it will move to the next step. But alongside with API we will update command line tools on build workers so it will be one-liner.